# How to passing params whit file upload and get it in node js from Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to passing params whit file upload and get it in node js from Ionic 3 I use express Js `4.16.4` I use multer to upload image

Comment: The Solution worked for me it: i upload Image first get image name in return and send complete data with image name to another API.

Comment: thanks for answer , you seperate the link when upload finish you call antoher link but how to know if this upload is for this data ?

Comment: Make 2 different links or API. example: `https://web-url.com/imageUpload` for image and `https://web-url.com/dataUpload` for complete data with image name.

Comment: i need to store the name of image in the database whit the data and if i do 2 links maybe 2 personnes publish image in same time and this can give an issue how to know if this image its for this data

Comment: It will not create any issue. Just try this.

Comment: how to link the file whit the data if it's two separated links ?